# After downloading file .obb not find the next scene

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, unityscript

I am making an application in Unity3D and I have a problem with the file .obb. After downloading the file .obb from my dropbox try to open the next scene and tells me I can not find it. If I close the application and return open functioning OK. What can be?

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.IO;
using System;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class DownloadFile : MonoBehaviour {

private string path;
private string url = "";
private float m_CurrentValue = 0;

public GameObject btnStart;
private string nextScene = "Splash";

void log( string t )
{
    print("MYLOG " + t);
}

// Use this for initialization
void Start ()
{
    CheckObb ();
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

}

void CheckObb()
{

    if (!GooglePlayDownloader.RunningOnAndroid())
    {
        log ( "Use GooglePlayDownloader only on Android device!");
        return;
    }

    string expPath = GooglePlayDownloader.GetExpansionFilePath();

    if (expPath == null)
    {
        log("External storage is not available!");
    }
    else
    {
        string package = GooglePlayDownloader.Package();
        int version = GooglePlayDownloader.Version();

        path = String.Format("{0}/main.{1}.{2}.obb", expPath, version, package);
        url = String.Format("https://www.dropbox.com/s/xxxxxxxxxxxxxx/main.{0}.{1}.obb?dl=1", version, package);

        if (File.Exists(path))
        {
            // After downloading the file if you close the game and you become open, OK ¿?
            Application.LoadLevel(nextScene);
        }
        else
        {
            //check if directory doesn't exit
            if(!Directory.Exists(expPath))
            {  
                //if it doesn't, create it
                Directory.CreateDirectory(expPath);
            }

            btnStart.SetActive(true);
        }
    }
}

// Click Start button download obb
public void ClickStart()
{
    btnStart.SetActive(false);
    StartCoroutine(DownloadObb());
}

// Download obb
IEnumerator DownloadObb() {
    WWW download = new WWW(url);
    while( !download.isDone ) {
        m_CurrentValue = download.progress * 100;
        yield return null;
    }
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(download.error)) {
        //Error
    } else
    {
        // success!
        File.WriteAllBytes (path, download.bytes);
        // Here says that there is the scene
        Application.LoadLevel(nextScene);
    }
}
}
```

I tried to upload the apk and obb as alpha version in the developer console but when I go to download the .obb tells me this:
"Download failed because the resources could not be found"

Thanks.

Comment: Don't use the unity tag as it is not what you are asking for.

Answer (score 0):

I follow [this](http://www.exoa.fr/tutorial-unity-4-apk-splitting-google-play-obb/) tutorial in order to split my Unity app into *.obb file. It help me a lot.

Now, when I was performing my test in GooglePlay as an Alpha version everything goes OK, the download of the obb file and the process in the app but it doesn`t load my first scene.

It took me a lot to notice that when I put the loader as the scene 0 my index to load the next Scene was wrong. I know it is a poor error but thats the History behind my 10 hours research.

Hope you'll find useful.